# In review mode we have no alert when we try to edit a pending review question

Tags: discussion, bug, error-message

I read a question from review page, I would like to edit it to format the code but the button doesn't works, with no message.
I go to the question page, click on edit and I had this error message:

[image]

So I think there is a bug when another editing is awaiting approval, this message doesn't appear on [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review) page

Comment: Relevant: [Editing a post during review doesn't show an 'edit not possible' message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298797/editing-a-post-during-review-doesnt-show-an-edit-not-possible-message) as reported on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: This still doesn't appear to be fixed.

Comment: I've been seeing this issue for awhile now too.